# Проблема "pod has unbound immediate persistentvolumeclaims" при деплойменте Jenkins через Helm чарт

Tags: docker, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция, kubernetes

Всем привет. У меня есть виртуальная машина с Linux Ubuntu 18.x в котором развернут кластер microk8s. Я пытаюсь в нем сделать деплой Jenkins  при помощи Helm. После инсталяции чарта под не стартует и выводится сообщение в дашбоарде "pod has unbound immediate persistentvolumeclaims". Хотя PVС создана и имеет статус bound. Нужен хоть како-то намёк в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае проблема была в поврежденной  "IPtables FORWARD policy". Что выяснилось при помощи команды "microk8s.inspect". Из-за этого инит контейнер не мог получить доступ к интернету и стопорил деплоймент пода с основным контейнером. Решение оказалось элементарным - "sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT" и повторный деплоймент через хелм.